# How to get device current location while offline in android

Tags: android

I'm doing an android application which can show current location of device in offline mode while travel.so i'm trying to get device connected tower location.Below is the link i tried for getting gsm cellId.But i couldn't able to get Tower location(tower location name or lat/lang) without internet.How could i do that?Is it possible in android?Thanks.

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/get-location-of-cell-id-from.html

Comment: Why don't you take the coordinates with the GPS ?

Comment: Here is the link to achieve your requirement http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: what was your code?researches? effort? 

Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)